# Start python .exe on Windows File Server very slow

Tags: python-3.x, windows, exe, fileserver

My job is about office automation. Make some automated scripts for other teams in the company.
My company use Window File Server to store, backup, share data between each team.

And my team had set up a process that how other teams use the scripts we had developed. It is that we put the .exe file on the file server and use some tools to connect all scripts and make a group for other teams respectively.

The problem is that when I put my .exe file (which created by python) on file server and start it, it needs almost 20 seconds to show up the UI. But when I start it locally it just needs 2 or 3 seconds.
My colleagues use VB.Net to develop .exe and not show this situation. It shows the UI as fast as locally openning it.

I use both pyinstaller and Nuitka to compile my python to an .exe file (`--one directory`) but has same result (Run slowly on the file server when start up). I know convert python code to c/c++ will improve the speed when start the .exe so I use Nuitka. It performs well locally actually.
I am fresh for the company and before I came in, they had developd 90+ scripts by this process. I think I can't change the work flow they had built.

BTW, I heard that python .exe will download all dependencies to local from file server and run, does it true?
Any idea for this situation? Thanks.

Comment: Do not use .exe if possible. The exe file will decompress the zip file in itself to a temporary directory, Such directory contain all/most python installation + libraries, and then it call the python.exe inside it. At every execution. So, either requires Python installed on all machine, and you deliver only the script. Or put the scripts (and python) in your shared disk, and execute from there the commands (you should be careful on permissions (put it read-only), and all windows stuffs.

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi Thanks for reply. I will discuss with my team this week!

Comment: the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)